# NASM question regarding non-empty bin file

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bios

I'm trying to generate a small binary file to emulate a BIOS,
since I need for the first opcode to be at a specific location, I expect for the file to be at least that location in size but it generates just a small amount of bytes.

Do you have a specific syntax to generate the empty space training the initial opcode?

I paste a small 4 line code, to show my point, it only generates a 3 byte binary

```
org 0x7FF0
    jmp start

start:
    hlt
```

it genrates

```
0000000 00eb 00f4                              
0000003
```

Comment: What are those three bytes?

Comment: I just added the binary output to the post.

Comment: See https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdo12.html#section-12.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the wording of the question that is confusing or the code sample. If you want to create a 32KiB ROM/BIOS image where the entry point is offset 0x7FF0 but the code and data is earlier in the image you could do something like:

```
bits 16

; Assume BIOS code/data is loaded into memory at the beginning
; of some unspecified segment and all references are relative
; to offset 0x0000
org 0x0000

start:
    ; Insert BIOS code and data here

    hlt

; Pad BIOS image from beginning of section ($$) to 32KiB-16
TIMES 32*1024-16-($-$$) db 0x00

; Emit the bootstrap JMP
bios_entry:
    jmp start

; Pad BIOS image to 32KiB
TIMES 16-($-bios_entry) db 0x00
```

The assumption is that the 32KiB ROM/BIOS image is placed at some unspecified real mode segment where all references are relative to the beginning of that segment. The label `start` could be placed anywhere in the image (except the last 16 bytes), not necessarily at the beginning.

It wasn't uncommon for this type of thing to be done in BIOSes where the bootstrap was placed in the last paragraph (16 bytes) of the image.

Assemble to `bios.bin` with:

```
nasm -f bin bios.asm -o bios.bin
```

The file should be exactly 32768 bytes (32KiB). `hexdump bios.bin` should result in a file that contains this:

> ```
> 0000000 00f4 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
> 0000010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
> *
> 0007ff0 0de9 0080 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
> 0008000
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
    TIMES 0x7FF0 db 0
    jmp start
start:
    hlt
```

This will produce a file of 0x7FF3 bytes **but** I sincerily doubt that it will be useful. If you plan on reading this file so the `jmp start` lands on linear address 0x00007FF0, you will have overwritten all the important stuff in memory like the interrupt vector table, the BIOS variables, ...

If you need the first opcode to be at a specific location, just load the small 3-byte file at that particular address.
If you use the BIOS LoadSector function, you might want to extent the code to fill a full 512-byte sector:

```
    jmp start
start:
    hlt
    TIMES 512-3 db 0
```

Then load it at `ES:BX` equal to 0x07FF:0x0000`.